# How to increase Vdss of power MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, ac, powermosfet, tesla-coil

I want to build a Tesla coil with mains voltage. I found a schematic online but it uses an irfp460n MOSFET which can handle 500v (Vdss) but I only have couple of irfp260n and irf250n MOSFETs with 200v max Vdss. I will be using 230v half wave rectified dc.
The question is, Can I increase the max Vdss of MOSFETs by connecting them in some configuration and also how to connect them?

[image]

Comment: _"I want... but I only have... Can I"_-  You can't always get what you want... get what you need!

Comment: Welcome. Wishful thinking does not make electronics work. Having the right parts does.

Comment: There are ways to series switching devices to handle higher voltages, power companies do it all the time to use 1000 V devices to handle 200 kV DC/AC stations. However, it's very, very difficult, works well only at low frequencies, and you only do when there is **absolutely no alternative** and have lots and lots of money to spend and time to engineer it properly. In your case, buy the 500 V part, or step your AC down to about 60 V so the 200 V devices will work.

Comment: Since you are dealing with the oscillator circuit, It will introduce all sorts of problems even if you divide the voltage by connecting them in series. Not all semiconductors are identical.